# Nginx subdomain + subfolder to subfolder

Tags: nginx, subdomain, directory

The goal is to load pages from blog.example.com/blog using example.com/blog and all the posts, categories and authors.

```
location /blog(/.*)$ {
  rewrite ^ $1 break;

  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_pass https://blog.example.com/blog$1;
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

Gives a 500 error

Comment: If `blog.example.com` is publicly reachable, this will lead duplicate content, which is bad for SEO. You need to at least set canonical URLs properly.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen that has all been handled

Answer (score 0):

If the URI is passing through unchanged (e.g. `/blog/foo` -> `/blog/foo`) then you do not need a `rewrite` and you do not need the *optional* URI part on the `proxy_pass` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

The syntax of your `location` statement is wrong. You are using a regular expression without the appropriate operator `~` or `~*`. However, you do not need to use a regular expression to match all URIs that begin with `/blog`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass https://blog.example.com;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

Comment: I got

failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 1.2.3.4, server: example.com, request: "GET /blog

Comment: It sounds like it's trying to connect to itself. Are you sure that these are two distinct servers.

Comment: Yes currently same server, but end goal would be two different servers